# Impossible Alias field name

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

My client wants to use the following field name for an Access query:
"Mon-Tue+Wed"  without the quotes.  It is to remind him and anyone looking at the report that they are subtracking Monday and Tuesday earnings, but adding in Wednesday for this field. (Don't ask why...)

Nothing seems to work
"Mon-Tue+Wed" keeps the quotes
[Mon-Tue+Wed] gives a syntax error

I am stumpped.

Comment: Your client is dumb and should feel dumb.

Comment: This is not possible, and you'll need to tell your client so.

Comment: @MikeFal is right - this is a dumb idea, but customers are allowed to be dumb. I've just checked (I've only got Access 2013 to hand) and the name is valid without the quotes.

Comment: I've always felt that it's my job to steer people away from dumb. Especially when the idea is this impossibly dumb. No amount of work around is worth doing. Sometimes it's better to just explain to the client why something is a bad idea and put your foot down.

Comment: Thanks Rhys. We were all too concerned about the dumb client that we missed the elephant --obvious simple answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are outputing to a Report and not just query results, you can name the field whatever you like, and just replace the text/description labels in the report.